# Change default url from index.php to index.html in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, configuration, redirect

I have a web-site created with Joomla. I have two different index pages. One of them is "index.php" and the other one is "index.html". I want to set default page as "index.html" when I browse the URL of the site (However, now, the active default page is index.php). I have a href from that .html page to index.php. I have not change the content of index.php.

How can I change it from a configuration page or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the web server you are using, if you are using Apache, it's the `DirectoryIndex` configuration you need to change, see [here](http://bignosebird.com/apache/a2.shtml). For other types of server, I don't know, you'll need to read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Using an .htaccess file, you can change the index file to something else other than any of the index defaults. To do this, insert the below line into an .htaccess file.

> DirectoryIndex index.html index.php